# Please clarify my understanding on bit fields and Unions in C

Tags: c, cpu-registers, unions, bit-fields

I am looking into a microcontroller driver files and had trouble understanding the proper use of Unions and Bit Fields

```
typedef union
{
     uint8 U;                          //Unsigned 
     sint8 I;                          //signed 
     Register_x_Bits B;                //Bit field access 
}u1;

typedef struct _Register_x_Bits        //8 bit register size 
{
    uint8 Field1:1;                    //endianness is maintained for all registers      
    uint8 Field2:1;                
    uint8 Field3:1;                    
    uint8 Field4:1;                   
    uint8 Field5:4;    
}Register_x_Bits;


u1 reg;

reg.U = ReadRegister();                 // data is initially being read from the register 

//based on the previous data  a bit value needs to be changed in particular location of the data 

reg.B.Field3 = 0;

WriteRegister(reg.U);
```

And here is where i have trouble understanding

1) By changing just the`reg.B.Field3` bit field value, would it change only one particular bit (Field 3  in this case) or does it clear all the previous data in the register and fill it with new `reg.B.Field3`

Many tutorials state that there would be only one active member in `Unions`

2) Can i change multiple bit fields in the same register ?
Can i change them by the same method above and  keeping the remaining intact

```
reg.B.Field1 =0;
reg.B.Field3 =1;
reg.B.Field4 =1100;
```

**Edits**
[image]

Let the whole register value to be `1111 0 1 0 1` and now if i change `Fields 1,3,4` would it effect the value in `Fields 0,2` ?

Comment: You have to define `Register_x_Bits` before you use it in a union definition.  The code shown shouldn't compile.  (But you can easily reverse the order of the union and the structure so that it will compile.)

Comment: You can't fit all of decimal 1100 into a 4-bit field.  Did you have in mind 6 as the value?  (1100 % 16 is 12, which is what you'd get with the code as written.)

Comment: Assigning to `reg.B.Field3` would not change the other bits in the `reg.B` structure.  It would affect the values in `reg.I` and `reg.U` — in practice, one bit would be reset, but which bit is implementation defined (most of bit field behaviour is implementation defined, so you have to look at the implementation manual — and demand the information if it is not already documented in the manuals you have).

Comment: Is there a typo in your `Register_x_Bits` structure since `Field4` is typed twice?

Comment: @oysteijo .. Oh i dint notice that ...its a  typo. I corrected it now

Answer (score 1):

Okay first check the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct _BITS{
    unsigned char f1:1;
    unsigned char f2:1;
    unsigned char f3:1;
    unsigned char f4:1;
    unsigned char f5:4;

}BITS;
typedef union {
    unsigned char a;
    char b;
    BITS c;
}u1;

int main(void) {
    u1 reg;
    reg.a = 255;
    reg.c.f1 = 0;
    //reg.c.f2 = 1;
    printf("%d", reg.c.f1);
    printf("%d", reg.c.f2);
    return 0;
}
```

To mimic `ReadRegister()`, I wrote `reg.a = 255`. So now when I write `reg.c.f1 = 0` and if it was changing all the bits then `reg.c.f2` will print 0 too. But it doesn't happen. Bitfield are only targeted for that particular bit, not the whole byte. Hence **No it would only clear that bit**

Now if I write `reg.a = 0` and `reg.c.f1 = 255` and if it was setting all the bits then `reg.c.f2` would yield 1 but it won't. Hence **No you can't set all the bits of the bit field**

**Edit**
However you can set multiple bits in other ways..See @sdao's answer

Hope that answers your question

Comment: I've added a registers bit description in my question .. and if i have  `reg.a= 255` then change`reg.c.f1 = 0` and `reg.c.f4 = 0` would my `reg.a` change to `11110110`

Comment: You need to recap the the concept the of `unions` again. Here 2 points..1. If you change the one bit, other bit will not change..2. If you change one bit using bitfield, then the whole byte value is affected. Because 1. Each bit is distinct from other and 2. in `union` memory is shared and here only one variable is created and shared. Changes made through one will be reflected in other.

Comment: Please select my answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

1: You can change on field individually without affecting the others
2: You can change many fields at the same time.

F.Y.I: in your case, the value can be set to each field is `[0: sizeof(unsigned char)]` but the actual value that each field can receive depends on number of bits it is, so be careful
Assume you have **N** bit(s) field, you assign **M** to that field then the actual value that will be set is: `(M & (N^2 - 1))` where `(N^2 - 1)` is the mask.

Ex:

```
reg.B.Field1 = 10; // actual value: reg.B.Field1 = 0 (because 10 = b'0000 1010, Field1 is 1 bit field then the mask is `1^2 - 1 = 1 (b'1)`), 10 & 1 = 0)
reg.B.Field3 = 7;  // actual value: reg.B.Field3 = 1 (because 7 = b'0000 0111, Field3 is 1 bit field then the mask is `1^2 - 1 = 1 (b'1)`, 7 & 1 = 1)
reg.B.Field4 = 24; // actual value: reg.B.Field4 = 8 (because 24 = b'0001 1000, Field4 is 4 bits field then the mask is `4^2 - 1 = 15 (b'1111)`, 24 & 15 = 8)
```